# Is this sentence grammatically correct? [I'm passionate about anything marketing]

Tags: grammar, verbs

I've seen some sentences that use the word 'anything' with a noun or adjective such as 'anything crystal'. Can you use 'anything' followed by a verb? i.e. i love anything speaking/writing.

Comment: Very closely related: [What does 'all things X' mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/what-does-all-things-x-mean). In fact I think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I think that 'marketing' is not a verb or a participle but a noun:"The commercial functions involved in transferring goods from producer to consumer. American Heritage Dictionary."

The speaker in the sentence is passionate about anything to do with those commercial activities.